# SQL Server Stored Procedure temp tables return incorrect results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, temp-tables

I have very weird problem with my SQL Server stored procedure. Any time I run this stored procedure it returns different result values. I am using 3 temp tables and as final result I am summarizing some columns.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, here is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [plannabavki].[SumarnoKonta] 
    @godina1 int,
    @godina2 int,
    @godina3 int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
if OBJECT_ID('a2014s') is not null
drop table a2014s
if OBJECT_ID('a2015s') is not null
drop table a2015s
if OBJECT_ID('a2016s') is not null
drop table a2016s

--razlika = planirano-procjenjeno
create table a2014s (ktto nvarchar(30),kttonaziv nvarchar(max),planirano money,procjenjena money,razlika money)
create table a2015s (ktto nvarchar(30),kttonaziv nvarchar(max),planirano money,procjenjena money,razlika money)
create table a2016s (ktto nvarchar(30),kttonaziv nvarchar(max),planirano money,procjenjena money,razlika money)


insert into a2014s (ktto,kttonaziv,planirano,procjenjena,razlika)
select [Ktto],[KttoNaziv],sum(case when pk.NP1 is null then 0 else pk.NP1 end),sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end),sum(case when pk.NP1 is null then 0 else pk.NP1 end)-sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end) 

  FROM [dbo].[Stavke] as st
  inner join [dbo].[PlanskaKalkulacija] as pk on st.Ktto=pk.KontoId
  where Godina=@godina1 and PlanskaKalkulacija_Id=1
  group by ktto,KttoNaziv
  order by ktto

  insert into a2015s (ktto,kttonaziv,planirano,procjenjena,razlika)
select [Ktto],[KttoNaziv],sum(case when pk.NP2 is null then 0 else pk.NP2 end),sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end),sum(case when pk.NP2 is null then 0 else pk.NP2 end)-sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end) 

  FROM [dbo].[Stavke] as st
  inner join [dbo].[PlanskaKalkulacija] as pk on st.Ktto=pk.KontoId
  where Godina=@godina2 and PlanskaKalkulacija_Id=1
  group by ktto,KttoNaziv
    order by ktto

  insert into a2016s (ktto,kttonaziv,planirano,procjenjena,razlika)
select [Ktto],[KttoNaziv],sum(case when pk.NP3 is null then 0 else pk.NP3 end),sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end),sum(case when pk.NP3 is null then 0 else pk.NP3 end)-sum(case when st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] is null then 0 else st.[ProcjenjenaVrijednostNabavke] end) 
  FROM [dbo].[Stavke] as st
  inner join [dbo].[PlanskaKalkulacija] as pk on st.Ktto=pk.KontoId
  where Godina=@godina3 and PlanskaKalkulacija_Id=1
  group by ktto,KttoNaziv
    order by ktto

select a2014s.ktto,a2014s.kttonaziv, 
sum(case when a2014s.planirano is null then 0 else a2014s.planirano end) as 'PlaniranoI',sum(case when a2014s.procjenjena is null then 0 else a2014s.procjenjena end)as 'ProcjenjenoI',sum(case when a2014s.razlika is null then 0 else a2014s.razlika end) as 'RazlikaI',
sum(case when a2015s.planirano is null then 0 else a2015s.planirano end) as 'PlaniranoII',sum(case when a2015s.procjenjena is null then 0 else a2015s.procjenjena end)as 'ProcjenjenoII',sum(case when a2015s.razlika is null then 0 else a2015s.razlika end) as 'RazlikaII',
sum(case when a2016s.planirano is null then 0 else a2016s.planirano end) as 'PlaniranoIII',sum(case when a2016s.procjenjena is null then 0 else a2016s.procjenjena end)as 'ProcjenjenoIII',sum(case when a2016s.razlika is null then 0 else a2016s.razlika end) as 'RazlikaIII'
 from a2014s
    left join a2015s on a2014s.ktto=a2015s.ktto
    left join a2016s on a2014s.ktto=a2016s.ktto
    where a2014s.[ktto] is not null
 group by a2014s.ktto,a2014s.kttonaziv
   order by ktto

drop table a2014s
drop table a2015s
drop table a2016s

END
```

Here are screen shots with different results for three time running (but data in db are not changed at all)

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=wjgfex&s=8#.UzGf4fldUn4]
[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=1z2d0uf&s=8#.UzGgQfldUn4]
[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ut5f87&s=8#.UzGgW_ldUn4]

Here are results differences

[image: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=b8mnsz&s=8#.UzGqpvldUn4]

You can see that values are different at row 3 but data in tables are not updated or changed. I just run this stored procedure 3 times.

Comment: Can you explain how the results are different?  It would help if you edited the question to include two different result sets that you see.

Comment: Please check this link http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=b8mnsz&s=8#.UzGqpvldUn4   you will see 3 results look any row and values are different but nothing changed in tables.

Comment: . . The results are probably just in a different order.  Your `order by` statement is not stable, because there can be multiple rows for the key.

Comment: I removed 'order by' and same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by deleting these temp tables that are somehow created inside DB.
Also I delete 'order by' command in all queries (advise from Gordon thanx).

Now I am getting non changed results from this SP.

Removed temp tables:
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2q1flu8&s=8#.UzGyZPldUn4